# MS Access: Why am I getting an "Invalid use of property" error?

Tags: vba, ms-access

I'm getting the error in the title when using this code:

```
Private Sub Command12_Click()

    Dim dbsCurrent As Database
    Set dbsCurrent = CurrentDb
    Dim query As QueryDef
    Dim sql As String

    item_entered = Me.Text314.Value

    sql = "Update tbl_FilmZipInfo Set qty_per_unit = Me.Text317 WHERE [item] = item_entered ;"

    query = CurrentDb.CreateQueryDef("UpdateFilmZip", sql)

    query.Execute

End Sub
```

After I run the Sub, the "Private Sub Command12_Click()" line gets highlighted in yellow and the "query =" gets highlighted in blue (the same blue highlighting that a human does when copying something). Anyone know why I am getting this error? The goal here is to update a specific record in a table.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to use the `Set` keyword when assigning object variables:

```
Set query = CurrentDb.CreateQueryDef("UpdateFilmZip", sql)
```

Comment: Ah, right. Can I bug you one more time? It's now giving me a "Too few parameters. Expected 2" error. It highlights the "query.Execute" line in yellow. Any ideas?

Comment: What does the documentation say for the Execute method?  The error message is pretty clear...it says you need two args and you provided zero.

Comment: [Hmm I need to fix that description](https://i.stack.imgur.com/doWGn.png).

Comment: @rory.ap in another Private Sub I used it in the exact same manner ("query.Execute") and it worked, so I don't see what is causing the error to appear *this time*.

Comment: @user7389351 it's the query string that has the parameters, not the `Execute` method.....

Comment: @Mat'sMug 1) How did you bring up that screen in your imgur screenshot? 2) I gave it the 2 parameters it asked for - a name and the sql variable (which is the SQL code I want to run)

Answer (score 1):

You must concatenate correctly:

```
sql = "Update tbl_FilmZipInfo Set qty_per_unit = " & Me!Text317.Value & "  WHERE [item] = '" & item_entered & "';"
```

Leave out the last quotes if item_entered is numeric.

Comment: Is there any way in VBA to get around SQL injection?

Comment: @rory.ap glad you asked! This now relates to that other Private Sub I was talking about! Yes, there is a way - you parametrize the query. Voila: `sql = "parameters " & _
        "P1 Date, P2 Text, P3 Text, P4 Number, P5 Time, P6 Number, P7 Text, P8 Text, P9 Number, P10 Number, P11 Number, P12 Number, P13 Number, P14 Number, P15 Number, P16 Number, P17 Number;" & _
        "INSERT INTO ...VALUES ([P1], [P2], [P3], [P4], [P5], [P6], [P7], [P8], [P9], [P10], [P11], [P12], [P13], [P14], [P15], [P16], [P17])"`

Comment: Both the answers helped fix the entire code. Thanks!